# Problem with scanning a multi dimensional array

Tags: arrays

My homework is to read a sudoku1.txt file and check if the sudoku puzzle is valid. Right not I am just trying to scan the .txt file into an array (arr[9][9]). I print the array right after but I find that the first value in the .txt file gets skipped, not scanned into the array. Why is this happening?

```
int main() {
int i, j,num;
int arr[9][9];
FILE* inp;
inp = fopen("sudoku1.txt", "r");
if (inp == NULL) {
    printf("file not found\n");
}
else {
    while (fscanf(inp,"%d",&num) != EOF) {
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) {
            for (j = 0; j < 9; j += 1) {
                fscanf(inp, "%d", &arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < 9; i += 1) {
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j += 1) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("\n\n");
```

}

Comment: Please add a language tag

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below. You first put a number in `num`, then you try to put 9*9 numbers into the array. That's why you lost your first number.

The first number is in num because of the line below

```
while (fscanf(inp,"%d",&num) != EOF)
```

Comment: What goes in place of num? I tried putting my array there and it didn't work.

Comment: maybe try to remove the while loop?